# Tweet using Selenium Python chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have no idea why this code does not work properly. 
This program is for automatically locating respective fields of username, password, and enter some data for the tweet to be sent. I am selecting the elements of the page correctly, but not able to enter data into it and get a

> NoSuchElement

Exception .

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import selenium

chromedriver = "mypathto/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
username = driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
password= driver.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
username.send_keys("myusername")
password.send_keys("password")



submit = driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary EdgeButtom--medium")
submit.click()

autotw1= driver.find_element_by_id('tweet-box-home-timeline')
autotw1.send_keys("""Just a testing """)
print "Tweet probably sent"

driver.save_screenshot("mybotfunc.png")
```

Comment: What is the version of chrome, Selenium driver you're using?

Comment: @SarveshEB `why this code does not work properly` where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: After finding the username and password element by field, I am not able to do ' driver.send_keys("username") ' . It throws an 'ElementNotVisible' error

Comment: @Sarvesh EB : check my answer and update us with result !

Comment: @JeffC The problem statement has been explicitly stated in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='Phone, email or username']")
password= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class='js-password-field']")
username.send_keys("your username")
password.send_keys("your password")

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log in']")
submit.click()

autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id='tweet-box-home-timeline']")))
autotw1.send_keys("""Just a testing """)  

tweet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='add-tweet-button ']//following-sibling::button[contains(@class,'tweet-action')]")
tweet.click()
```

Why your code is not working :

there are 3 element available with this name : `session[username_or_email]`
Several with this :  `session[password]`
and 2 with this id : `tweet-box-home-timeline`

Comment: Okay, your code works, but when I add another line of code
tweet= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Tweet']")
tweet.click()
It fails to do that, since that is the sole purpose of this program.
Also, can you debug or explain why my code doesn't work

Comment: answer my above comment please. I am no able to send the tweet.

Comment: there is something wrong with xpath : //button[text()='Tweet'] , I am trying to solve it

Comment: @JeffC Sir, I never urged anyone. If my tagging has bothered someone, I will avoid it.

Comment: @Sarvesh EB use this :   tweet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='add-tweet-button ']//following-sibling::button[contains(@class,'weet-action')]")
tweet.click()

Comment: @SarveshEB : I have added this code to my answer also. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @cruisepandey There is a typo in the last part of the first line of the updated code. Else, all's fine. Change "weet" into "tweet"